# How to edit postgresql dump files

Tags: postgresql, heroku, dump

I have a web app with the data stored in a postgresql database on heroku. I have built a new version of the app from scratch that changes the data structure in quite a few ways. Some columns are redundant; some tables are renamed etc. But I want to get the data into a format that I can add it to the new database. So I need to do some data wrangling. What tools and processes could I use to edit the dump of the database?

Answer (score 0):

You could import the old database into a separate one.  Then you can use regular SQL to copy the data over.